# Tap gesture not detected in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to detect a tap gesture on a UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell.

This is the part of the code inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let cell1 : cellTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! cellTableViewCell


        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        cell1.profileImg.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let tappedOnImage = UIGestureRecognizer(target: cell1, action: "tappedOnImage:")

        cell1.profileImg.tag = indexPath.row
        cell1.profileImg.addGestureRecognizer(tappedOnImage)
```

And here's the function handling the gesture:

```
func tappedOnImage(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){


    print("hey")
}
```

However, nothing is happening when I tap.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell what is wrong without seeing more code, but try this:

```
let tappedOnImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedOnImage:")
```

Comment: Unless your tappedOnImage function is implemented in the class cellTableViewCell.  If this is the case, then I would try instead adding the gesture recognizer in that class as well, instead of wherever cellForRowAtIndexPath is.

Comment: YEs everything is in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer is an abstract class.  In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method use UITapGestureRecognizer